# tengo un error que llevo días tratando de solucionar en android con flutter

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, dart, gradle

al momento de correr la aplicación me sale este error

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.40 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':google_api_headers' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()


}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

}

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 31

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede mostrar su pubspec.yaml? Creo que esto es un problema con el paquete Googe_api_headers. Este paquete está en su pubspec.yaml, o algún paquete depende de él. Actualice este paquete y haga 'flutter pub upgrade --major-versions' en su terminal para actualizar sus paquetes.

Comment: Cuales son las dependencias que usas en tu app/build.gradle?, escribirlas por favor

Comment: Intenta actualizar los siguientes parámetros: **- Archivo android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:**
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip